# Multiprocessing Pooling Fails at Dask Functions

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, dask

I am trying to take two arrays, "day 1": ranging from 0 to 11 (incremented by +1) and "day 2:" ranging from 11 to 0 (incremented by -1), and sum them.  However, I wish to use multiprocessing and dask arrays to speed up the process (I will be going to bigger numbers later).  I want to split day 1 and day 2 into four equal parts (day 1: [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11] and day 2: [11, 10, 9], [8, 7, 6], [5, 4, 3], [2, 1, 0]) and have four processes to add work on each consequent array (i.e., day1's [0, 1, 2] with day 2's [11, 10, 9] and get [11, 11, 11].  After all four processes are done, I hope to return back into one big list of [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11].  However, within the function of the bolded step, the code fails to run and is stuck in an infinite loop or calculations of some sort.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da
from dask import delayed
import threading
import multiprocessing as mp

NUM_WORKERS = 4

# create list from 0 to 11
day1 = list(range(12))
# create list form 11 to 0
day2 = day1[::-1]

def get_sum(i, base):
    z = []
    x = day1[i * length: i * length + length]
    y = day2[i * length: i * length + length]
    z.append(x)
    z.append(y)
    converted = da.from_array(z, chunks = NUM_WORKERS)
    **summed = da.sum(converted, axis = 0).compute()**
    list_concatenate = np.concatenate((base, summed), axis=0)
    all_sum = sum(list_concatenate)

process_list = []
for i in range(NUM_WORKERS):
    process_list = mp.Process(target = get_sum, args = (i, process_list))
    process_list.start()
    process_list.join()
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? You're not protecting the top-level code in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, so (unless you're using the `fork` startmethod, which doesn't exist on Windows) each new process will create `NUM_WORKERS` new pool processes. See the [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) in the docs. If this is your problem, I can find a dup that explains it nicely.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you trying to manually build your own pool of workers and array slices, instead of using `multiprocessing.Pool`? Or, even better, the Dask scheduler? There doesn't seem much point in using Dask instead of NumPy for this otherwise.

Comment: I am using a mac.  I have also tried using pool, but am not too sure how to use it.  Could you possibly demonstrate how a dask scheduler may be used for this instance?

Comment: You need to work through the Dask tutorial; there are examples that are almost identical to what you're doing, and nothing I write on the fly is going to be as good as the tutorial.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of problems with this code, but I'm not sure which one if actually causing the problem you're asking about. (1) You're trying to use the same variable `process_list` to mean three different things: a list of `Process` objects, a single `Process` object, and an argument to `get_sum` (which tries to pickle each previous `Process` object to send it to the next `Process`). You're asking Dask to split the array into chunks repeatedly in each child process, instead of sending each child a chunk. You're then working on all of the chunks instead of just one.

Comment: Finally, you're not storing the results anywhere but in a temporary `all_sum` local that immediately goes away.